# Cognos Package Label Translation doesn't work

Tags: package, cognos, language-translation

I have an enviroment with Cognos 11.2.2. I've had some language on package with different label transalation ( ex English ) but when I try to use report studio all the label are showed in package design language.
The user language that I use to test the functionality is English

In other enviroment with different Cognos version translation works fine

Comment: be specific.  What languages are in use in the model?  Which language is the design language and which is the active language?

Comment: In the user's "Profile and settings" screen, what is the Product language and what is the Content language?

Comment: Every once in a while the view count increases by one.  I suspect it is you and me looking at it to see if this chap has answered the questions.  @dougp

Comment: I use en-zw as design language, and English as translated language.   English is set as Product Language and Content Language